# How to use a string as a function parameter in Python and have variable number of parameters

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I have a function called filter that accepts a number of parameters in the format name=value. I have 2 lists: names and values (let's call them x and y), I need to be able to pass these into the function.

When I just pass in the string as in the below example, it gives me an error:

```
x = ['t', 't2']
y = [w, w2]
filter(x[0]=y[0], x[1]=y[1])
```

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

I would also need to be able to pass in an arbitrary amount, for the size of the lists. How can I go about making this work?

Comment: Post the function declaration, please... It's hard to tell what you are expecting

Comment: Not sure how you have defined your filter but it seems you can just pass arguments as `filter(y[0],y[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `**kwargs`:

```
kwargs = {x[0]: y[0], x[1]: y[1]}
filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this was exactly it lol. New to kwargs, I thought I could pass in a dictionary but it wasn't really working before.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to have a function called filter as that will overwrite the built-in python filter function.  But otherwise read up on using [*args and **kwargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/), sounds like what you need.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks